# Python Insert using Priority

Tags: python, insert

```
from myNode import *
from tasks import *

class PriorityQueue():
    __slots__ = ( 'front', 'back', 'size' )

def mkPriorityQueue():
    queue = PriorityQueue()
    queue.front = NONE_NODE
    queue.back = NONE_NODE
    queue.size = 0
    return queue

def insert(queue, element):
    newnode = mkNode(element, NONE_NODE)
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        #if the queue was empty, the new node is now both the first and last one
        queue.front = newnode
        queue.back = newnode
    elif frontMax(queue).priority > newnode.data.priority:
        #if the new node has a higher priority than the first, insert at front
        newnode.next = queue.front #old first is now second node
        queue.front = newnode
    else:
        #the node has a lower priority than the first
        #find the next node with a lower priority, insert newnode before that
        currentnode = queue.front
        while not currentnode.next == NONE_NODE:
            #traverse nodes until we find a lower priority or until the end
            if currentnode.next.data.priority < newnode.data.priority:
                break
            currentnode = currentnode.next
        #insert newnode between currentnode and currentnode.next
        newnode.next = currentnode.next
        currentnode.next = newnode
        #if newnode.next is now NODE_NONE, we're at the end so change backMin
        if newnode.next == NONE_NODE:
            queue.back = newnode

    queue.size += 1

def removeMax(queue):
    """Remove the front element from the queue (returns None)"""
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        raise IndexError("Cannot dequeue an empty queue")
    queue.front = queue.front.next
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        queue.back = NONE_NODE
    queue.size -= 1

def frontMax(queue):
    """Access and return the first element in the queue without removing it"""
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        raise IndexError("front on empty queue")
    return queue.front.data

def backMin(queue):
    """Access and return the last element in the queue without removing it"""
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        raise IndexError("back on empty queue")
    return queue.back.data

def emptyQueue(queue):
    """Is the queue empty?"""
return queue.front == NONE_NODE
```

Am I doing that right? Below is that problem I am trying to solve. I have added all the function(s) I did.

inserts (Under the Insert Function) it using the priority rules (Each task has an integer priority from 10 
    (highest priority) to 1 (lowest priority). If two tasks have the same priority, the order should be based on the
    order they were inserted into the priority queue (earlier ﬁrst).

Comment: That's not a question. What exactly is your problem?

Comment: @l4mpi my bad. I edited it. I did not understand what it is asking me...

Comment: @l4mpi so you down-voted this post?

Comment: You're supposed to create an ordering of tasks based on their priority, starting with the highest priority in order of insertion and ending with the lowest priority. E.g. you have 5 tasks of priorities 5, 8, 4, 5, 6 inserted after another then the order would be 2, 5, 1, 4, 3.

Comment: And yes I downvoted this, as "I don't understand the wording / concepts behind my assignment" is really not the type of question you should ask here - especially without demonstrating any effort of understanding it on your part.

Comment: @l4mpi Yeah isn't this website all about helping?

Comment: Yes, and asking questions is about demonstrating that you deserve help - which you failed to do, but nevertheless I provided an example that should be helpful. You're obviously new to this site so please go read all of this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking , most importantly http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @l4mpi Can you check out the post edited? to see if I am doing it right? Thanks.

Comment: Yeah that's better. Well, your code has a number of problems, I'm gonna write up a quick answer...

Comment: @l4mpi also do you want to take a look at myNode.py and task.py?

Comment: I think it's not neccessary, as way you use it in your code gives me an idea of the relevant structures. You can check with my answer if I got it right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you've got a syntax error on your `else` statement which does not take a test expression. Besides that, your logic is off as it would not maintainin the correct node structure in `insert` - when you do `queue.firstMax = newnode`, you basically delete the current `firstMax` element as you no longer have a reference to it; you'll need to assign the old first element to `newnode.next` in this case. Also, if the priority of the new task is `<=` the current first, you'll need to traverse the queue to find the correct place for the new node to maintain the order - it's supposed to go before the first element with a lower priority. (In an optimized implementation, you would store the nodes separated by priority, or at least keep a reference to the last nodes of each priority, to speed up this insertion, but I guess this is outside the scope of this exercise.)

Here's an implementation of `insert` which should perform correctly:

```
def insert(queue, element):
    newnode = mkNode(element, NONE_NODE)
    if emptyQueue(queue):
        #if the queue was empty, the new node is now both the first and last one
        queue.frontMax = newnode
        queue.backMin = newnode
    elif frontMax(queue).priority > newnode.data.priority:
        #if the new node has a higher priority than the first, insert at front
        newnode.next = queue.frontMax #old first is now second node
        queue.frontMax = newnode
    else:
        #the node has a lower priority than the first
        #find the next node with a lower priority, insert newnode before that
        currentnode = queue.frontMax
        while not currentnode.next == NODE_NONE:
            #traverse nodes until we find a lower priority or until the end
            if currentnode.next.data.priority < newnode.data.priority:
                break
            currentnode = currentnode.next
        #insert newnode between currentnode and currentnode.next
        newnode.next = currentnodenode.next
        currentnode.next = newnode
        #if newnode.next is now NODE_NONE, we're at the end so change backMin
        if newnode.next == NODE_NONE:
            queue.backMin = newnode

    queue.size += 1
```

Comment: Thank you. Also, I have a one problem, in result I got: Highest priority task is Task1 with priority 5. Lowest priority task is Task2 with priority 9. Which it suppose to 9 (Highest), 5(Lowest). 

Also, I changed alot of wordings in different function.

Comment: I got it now! The operator suppose to be reverse!